# NoMethodError in Courses#edit undefined method `model_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I need help with the follow problem. I have been looking at similar questions but am still unable to find the solution to the problem. I am currently having this problem.

NoMethodError in Courses#edit

undefined method `model_name' for #Class:0xb5068474

the error seems to be with this line of code.

```
<%= simple_fields_for @lesson  do |f| %>
                <%= f.input :lesson_name %>
<%end%>
```

The lesson database is link to the course database, where course has_many lessons and lesson belongs_to course. I think that the problem may be due to my controller code. I am relatively new and not very sure about how to go about solving this problem.

I am able to go to create page to create that relation but nothing else is saved inside the database but the id of course and lesson. However, when i go to the edit page for course, this error pops out.

**courses_controller.rb**

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_course, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show,:index]
  # GET /courses
  # GET /courses.json
  def index
    @courses = Course.all
  end

  # GET /courses/1
  # GET /courses/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /courses/new
  def new
    @course = Course.new
    @lesson = @course.lessons.build
  end

  # GET /courses/1/edit
  def edit
     @course = Course.find(params[:id])
     @lesson = @course.lessons
  end

  # POST /courses
  # POST /courses.json
  def create
    @course = Course.new(course_params)
    @course.lessons.new(lesson_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.save
        format.html { redirect_to @course, notice: 'Course was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @course }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /courses/1
  # PATCH/PUT /courses/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.update(course_params)
        @course.lesson.update_attributes(lesson_params)
        @course.staff_ids=params[:course][:staff_ids]
        format.html { redirect_to @course, notice: 'Course was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /courses/1
  # DELETE /courses/1.json
  def destroy
    @course.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to courses_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_course
      @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def course_params
      params.require(:course).permit(:course_code, :course_name, :year_of_study,  :discipline, :Acad_unit, :cohort_size, :remark)
    end

    def lesson_params
      params.require(:lesson).permit(:lesson_type, :lesson_name, :num_lesson, :frequency)
    end
end
```

**lesson.rb**

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
end
```

**course.rb**

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :course_code, :course_name
  validates_uniqueness_of :course_code, :course_name
  validates :year_of_study, :Acad_unit, :cohort_size, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0}
  has_and_belongs_to_many :staffs, join_table: :scheduleCourse
  has_many :lessons, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Please give me some advise. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide Lesson and Course models code

Comment: added lesson and course models code

Answer (score 0):

The error that you get:

```
undefined method `model_name` for #Class:0xb5068474
```

Means that `simple_fields_for` method is doing something like `@lesson.class.model_name`, which is ok when object you pass (`@lesson`) is an instance of ActiveRecord::Base, but in `edit` action you define `@lesson`

```
@lesson = @course.lessons
```

As a relation, so it is not one `Lesson` instance, it is internal ActiveRecord object for storing relations. If for instance you call `first` on it:

```
@lesson = @course.lessons.first
```

This should work. Or you can iterate through collection of lessons in view to create form for each one of them, it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I want to create a few lesson at a go while creating a course. I tried chaning the @ lesson = @ course.lesson instead of lessons and it doesn't work. I try using @ lesson = @ course.lessons.first but it doesnt work too :x

Comment: That's probably beause you don't have anyting in lessons. Try `@course.lessons.build` in your controller, and in view `<% @course.lessons.each do |lesson| %>`. Check out nested forms manual, that's what you want to do https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models

Comment: i created 3 fields for user to enter 3 different lessons when creating the course. Each using <%= simple_fields_for @lesson  do |f| %>
                <%= f.input :lesson_name %>
<%end%>. Is that still done using <% @ course.lessons.each do |lesson| %>. The creation of course is alr a form, so it is alr considered a nested form?

Comment: you have to create nested form for lessons. in controller you do `3.times { @course.lessons.build }`, and in view ` <%= simple_form_for @course do |c| <%= c.simple_fields_for :lessons do |l| %><%= f.input :lesson_name %>`, or you can implement similar behavior with `lessons.each`